UITableView reordering controls are not showing in UIViewController
Not sure what is wrong, I feel like I've done this a thousand times over the years, but its not working this time.
I have a UIViewController (not UITableViewController) and I create a UITableView in loadView(). I set the delegate and the datasource. I implement the canMoveRowAt and the moveRowAt delegate methods. I add a UIBarButtonItem to tap to put the table into edit mode but none of the reorder controls show up.
class MyTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableview: UITableView!

    override func loadView() {
        // intentionally not calling super
        
        self.tableview = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        self.tableview.delegate = self
        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.view = self.tableview
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        let reorderbutton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "mount"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(tappedreorder(_:)))
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [reorderbutton]
    }
        
    @objc func tappedreorder(_ sender:Any) {
        self.tableview.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        config.text = ...
        cell.contentConfiguration = config
        
        return cell
    }
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("moved row from \(sourceIndexPath) to \(destinationIndexPath)")
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        print("can move row at \(indexPath), true")
        return true
    }
    
}

When I set the table into editing mode, I don't get any calls backs to canMoveRowAt and none of the rows show the reorder controls.
I've also tried adding cell.showsReorderControl = self.tableview.isEditing to the cellForRowAt implementation so that it explicitly requests the move control, but that didn't change anything because none of the rows were actually being reloaded. Even when I set the table into edit mode and then did a reloadData() to reload all the rows and set  cell.showsReorderControl, they still didn't show up.

I copy/pasted your code ... changed config.text = ...  to config.text = "\(indexPath)" ... implemented the missing numberOfRowsInSection ... and tapping the navBar button gives me this: https://i.sstatic.net/gKyzg0Iz.png

@DonMag I do have a numberOfRowsInSection and in my implementation I was pretty much setting the text to indexPath just like you did... but it's not working. That's what is so confusing. It looks like it should... but it isn't. I don't understand it. I feel like I've done this a 1000 times and it's always worked... but SOMETHING is weird and going wrong. :(

I figured it out, I messed myself up because I didn't want the Delete control to appear when I went into Edit mode, and I messed up which method to do that with.
The wrong thing I did was:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

My list is showing a list of built-in reports and custom-user reports. I didn't want the user to be able to delete the built-in reports, so I wrongly used canEditRowAt to turn off the delete control. But what I should have done was this:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .none
}

Using the editingStyleForRowAt would let me turn off the Delete control and still allow a Reorder control. But using canEditRowAt turned off all of the editing controls, including the reorder control that I was trying to get.
